# difference between swfLoader and ModulLoader

Tags: apache-flex

what is difference between swfLoader(load application) and ModuleLoader(load module)?
which is better to use?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SWFLoader is used to load sub-applications while the ModuleLoader is used to load Modules, as you stated yourself.

The difference is that Modules have a tight link to the application their are loaded in and cannot be used standalone. A subapplication on the other hand really is a separate application that has no direct link to the application it is loaded in. Depending on your use cases, you might consider one or the other.

There is a good stuff available from Adobe **[here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf619ab-7fe2.html)**

Be sure to check the section "[Comparing loaded applications to modules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f07.html)".